# Function output empty by succesfull AJAX response

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

There's an issue with my function in the AJAX.
I create an AJAX call to a PHP file that returns JSON.

For loop this JSON I created a fucntion that I run if the AJAX is successfull.
But in practice the data is empty.

```
    <script>
    document.getElementById("getproducts").addEventListener("submit", sendAjax);
    function sendAjax(event) {
    var q = document.getElementById('search').value;
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                display(this.responseText);
            }
        }
        xhttp.open("POST", "results.php", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.send('search='+q);
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    function display( jsdata ){
        for ( var key in jsdata ){
            var htmltabel = '';
            var datanode = document.createElement("div");
            htmltabel += '<div class="id">' + jsdata[key]['id']    + '</div>';
            content    = htmltabel;
            datanode.innerHTML = content;
            document.getElementById("resultt").appendChild(datanode);
        }
    }
    </script>
```

If I code the JSON hardcode in the function like this than everything is okay.

```
var hardcoded = {"1736":{"id":"1736","post_title":"Test explode","_sku":"12345","_stock":null,"_price":"9.50"}}
//PART OF THE CODE
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    display(hardcoded);
}
```

How can I fix this that the function use the responded JSON?

Comment: What do you get when you do `console.log(this.responseText)` in your `onreadystate` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a corrected script, You should just convert the responseData from `string` to `Json Object`!

```js
document.getElementById("getproducts").addEventListener("submit", sendAjax);
    function sendAjax(event) {
    var q = document.getElementById('search').value;
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                display( JSON.parse(this.responseText) ); // You should convert the response from string to a valid JSON
            }
        }
        xhttp.open("POST", "results.php", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.send('search='+q);
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    function display( jsdata ){
        for ( var key in jsdata ){
            var htmltabel = '';
            var datanode = document.createElement("div");
            htmltabel += '<div class="id">' + jsdata[key]['id']    + '</div>';
            content    = htmltabel;
            datanode.innerHTML = content;
            document.getElementById("resultt").appendChild(datanode);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean, from JSON to an object?

Comment: Absolutely, a JSON object

Comment: I don't mean to be blunt, but there is a difference between JSON and a JavaScript Object. Although they both look the same, JSON is a language independent format which borrows its notation from JavaScript, hence JavaScript Object Notation. A JavaScript Object is rather an actual value (or container of values) which can be interpreted and run by JavaScript. JSON can be converted to an object and vice versa, but they are not interchangeable. Don't mean anything by it and you provided the correct solution.

Comment: You are completely right! But by `JSON object` I meant a javascript object which is totally a normal object that we can use like a normal declared one. 
I said from `string` to `object` to to clarify that the `responseData` that we receive from the AJAX request is always `string` as long as we did not precise the `dataType`!